# how to add "jsx-control-statements"

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, create-react-app, babel-loader

I have ejected create-react-app using npm run eject.Now i have all the webpack config files.Do someone know how to add  [jsx-control-statements](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-jsx-control-statements) in Webpack config file?